# Command after SQL INSERT fails in my ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a page in ASP.NET MVC for my first year internship : it lets the employees input the amount of hours (between 0 and 8) spent per day of a month on a specific project.

The interface, display, selection and form sending seem to be working now - but once I do my SQL requests it seems to block right here :

```
foreach (string s in sDays)
{
    string[] values = s.Split(' ');
    string strQuery = "INSERT INTO UserActivity (CalendarDate,ProjectId,Login,TaskId,ActivityTypeId,Cost) VALUES (";
    strQuery += "'" + (new DateTime(iYear, iMonth, int.Parse(values[1]))).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'"; //We 2 donne [0] We et [1] 2
    strQuery += " , " + iProjectid;
    strQuery += " , '" + sLogin + "'";
    strQuery += " , NULL"; 
    strQuery += " , 0"; 
    strQuery += " , " + datas[i++];
    strQuery += ")";

    mDB_DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, m_strConnectionString);
    mDB_DataAdapter.Fill(mDB_DataSet, "UserActivity"); // Right here !
    mDB_DataAdapter = null;

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

And it directly sends me to :

```
catch (Exception ex) // The 'System.Data.SqlClient' provider is not registered on the local machine.
{
    bRet = false;
}
```

How come the command

```
mDB_DataAdapter.Fill(mDB_DataSet, "UserActivity");
```

makes it fail? Note that the majority of the code is not mine and is the last interns, I'm simply correcting bugs.

Here is my connectionStrings section of my Web.config :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CRAWebSiteMVC-20131119145412;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CRA" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CRA.csdl|res://*/Models.CRA.ssdl|res://*/Models.CRA.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008;initial catalog=CRAV34;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=as0;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="CRAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CRA.csdl|res://*/Models.CRA.ssdl|res://*/Models.CRA.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008;initial catalog=CRAV34;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=as0;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="CRAV34Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CRA.csdl|res://*/Models.CRA.ssdl|res://*/Models.CRA.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008;initial catalog=CRAV34;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=as0;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And the initialization of m_strConnectionString :

```
public UserActivityDb(string strConnectionString)
 {
            m_strConnectionString = strConnectionString;
 }
```

m_strConnectionString contains my connection string :

```
metadata=res://*/Models.CRA.csdl|res://*/Models.CRA.ssdl|res://*/Models.CRA.msl‌​;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=MMSDEVNEW\\SQL2008;initial catalog=CRAV34;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=as0;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework\
```

What is left to do is to save the input sent by the form and through this display it on the page.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :**

Replaced the whole OleDb nonesense with the following :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(m_strConnectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Works like a charm (apparently) but it doesn't display the info, I must now figure out how to display stored info in my Db.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the `catch` to see what the error is in `Exception ex`?

Comment: Do NOT compose your SQL commands with string concatenation. [Use parameters instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: [**USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!!!**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), if you don't you leave yourself open to malicious SQL Injection attacks, malformed SQL (which is probably what is causing your exception), data conversion/truncation errors, and you are unable to make use of cached query plans, forcing a recompilation of your query with every execution. In short there is not a single good reason to use string concatenation to form your SQL Statement.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post **(a)** the SQL that is being passed to the adapter when the exception is thrown, and **(b)** what the exception message is.

Comment: Thank you for your input considering the SQL Injections, I will take a look on it later on today, but for now I'm focusing on displaying the information I have stored / inserted into my Db.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417377/provider-for-sql-server-is-not-register-on-local-machine) will help, I see the poster also used OleDb and was getting the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [parameterised queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), if you don't you leave yourself open to malicious SQL Injection attacks, malformed SQL (which is probably what is causing your exception), data conversion/truncation errors, and you are unable to make use of cached query plans, forcing a recompilation of your query with every execution. In short there is not a single good reason to use string concatenation to form your SQL Statement.

You should use the [`System.Data.SqlClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace, if you are working with SQL Server, and since you are running an insert statement and not getting any results use [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).

So your final code might look like:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
....

string sql = @"INSERT UserActivity (CalendarDate, ProjectId, Login, ActivityTypeId, Cost)
                VALUES (@CalendarDate, @ProjectId, @Login, 0, @Cost);";

foreach (var s in days)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(strQuery))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@CalendarDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(iYear, iMonth, int.Parse(values[1]));
        command.Parameters.Add("@ProjectID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = iProjectid;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = sLogin;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Money).Value = datas[i++];

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying it out changing the names of variables to the good ones but I receive the following message : `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.` What does "Value" represent in the code you've share?  EDIT : I receive the error once I reach `using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sql))`

Comment: That line does not appear in what I have posted. You need to pass the connection string to the constructor of the SqlConnection, it appears as though you are passing the SQL statement.

Comment: Oh absolutely, my bad. It seems to work ! Thanks a lot for your input, I've learned from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing SQL Server, why are you using a `OleDbDataAdapter`? You should use a [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to OleDbDataAdapter, you should use SqlDataAdapter. Check this link- 
[Provider field in connection string oledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856466/provider-field-in-connection-string-oledb)

Answer (score 0):

Tutor time: 
it is not advisable to construct a sqlscript within your code because it can be injectable with another set of sql script if the use is knowledgeable.